# Update all content inside Dialog.

Tags: android, gridview, dialog, updates, android-gridview

I created GridView Gallery inside my Dialog. This gallery have some pages but for now for each one I create separated Dialog. All this Dialogs (gallery pages) different from each other by current progress (for example that I'm on 4/12 page) title and by photos (for each page i load different images). I'm thinking that creating new dialog for every page isn't good practive, but how should I do in just one dialog ?

One of my Dialogs code:

```
public void threeChoice()
    {
        Collections.sort(photoList = imageReader(photoDir,"1008"));
        inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();

        // Dialog layout
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_choice, null);

        progressDialog = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        //progressDialog = new ProgressBar(mContext);
        progressDialog.setMax(7);
        progressDialog.setProgress(3);


        gV = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridView);

        // GridAdapter (Pass context and files list)
        GridAdapter adapter = new GridAdapter(this, photoList);

        // Set adapter
        gV.setAdapter(adapter);



        final AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder2.setTitle("Album Page: 1008"); 

        builder2.setView(v);
        builder2.setPositiveButton("NEXT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                NextPage(); //<-- go to next page
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("BACK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                PreviousPage(); //<-- Back to previous page
            }
        });

        gV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PhotoDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra("image", photoList.get(position));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        builder2.setCancelable(false);
        final AlertDialog dialog = builder2.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the signature of `NextPage();` and `PreviousPage();` to `NextPage(View v);` and `PreviousPage(View v);`. Then you will be able to call them with your Dialog layout v and update this layout directly from your function.

Comment: But I only have 2 layout one with just gridView second with items (ImageView) so how it is to (View v) if i need to call imageReader function and do the rest stuff like update adapter etc

Comment: v does not contains all the views displayed in the dialog ?